# Put a ListView and TextView in a NavigationDrawerFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I successfully created a ListView and showed it as a sliding menu using the example provided by AndroidStudio to create a sliding menu

Now I want to add a layout above the ListView (showing the logged user's name and image, but to simplify I just want to put a TextView for now).

I tried the following, without success:

layout_menu.xml (Layout that appears when I want to show the menu. This was modified to put the textview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="User logged in"/>

    <ListView
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/fondo_menu"
        android:id="@+id/listaMenu"
        tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_base.xml (The one used by the activity that shows the menu, was not modified)

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BaseActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container">
    </ViewFlipper>

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.proyecto.cutcsa.cutcsa.Interfaz.ElementosUI.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/layout_menu"/><!--tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

NavigationDrawerFragment class (modified only the onCreateView to show the new menu)

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /*start modified code*/
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_menu, container, false);
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listaMenu);
        /*finish modified code*/
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
    }
```

But I am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` 
This error appears on the onCreate(), particularly on the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_base)` in the activity I want to show the menu.

The onCreate method I defined:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();
        try{
            mTitle = bundle.getString("title_menu");
        }catch(Exception ex){}

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What line does your Logcat say the Exception is happening on, and what *exactly* is on that line?

Comment: just added that on the edition

Comment: Can you post the `onCreate()` for your Activity, since that is where the error is occurring?

Comment: Why your navigation drawer is a Fragment? You can use the layout on the main activity.

Comment: I would suggest to use [android support design library](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) and its [`NavigationView`](http://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/). This way you can very easily create a good looking drawer.

Comment: I use a Fragment because is the way the example does..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the link below, you will get everything you need.
A very simple example of navigation drawer.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 0):

You trying to inflate your fragment 2 times, here:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.proyecto.cutcsa.cutcsa.Interfaz.ElementosUI.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/layout_menu"/><!--tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" -->
```

You can just add this layout(the navigation drawer content) to your activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- USE VIEWPAGER INSTEAD -->
    <ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container">
    </ViewFlipper>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="User logged in"/>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="@color/fondo_menu"
            android:id="@+id/listaMenu"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: and all the code embed with show/hide the menu, how is it handled?

Comment: android:layout_gravity="start" will control it

Comment: PLEASE reduce the ViewGroup dependency.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is greatly simplified with the [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

The article says to create your drawer like so:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The headerLayout refers to a layout to go above the list (your account details layout). The menu is a standard menu resource, an example of which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group
    android:id="@+id/nav_group_fragments"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home_one"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="@string/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_offers"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_my_offers"
        android:title="@string/offers"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_aroundme"
        android:title="@string/aroundme"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_around_me"/>
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/nav_group_activities">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_help"
        android:title="@string/help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_disconnect"
        android:title="@string/disconnect"/>

</group>
</menu>
```

A divider is automatically inserted for every group with an id you create

Comment: Unnecessary work and non recycling view... Glad your memory.

Comment: I get not resouce identifier found on headerLayout and menu. It seams it doesnt recognize those XML attributes

Comment: You need to include the support library to use this stuff: 

 compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' in your app's build.gradle